# Removing and reading from XML file

Tags: c#, xml

Whenever I try to remove an entry from the xml file using a button click it removes it from the form but it remains in the xml file. The other problem I am having is this:

I create a user in the program, it saves to the xml file. I close the program and load it back up the **first time** I load it back up after putting the entry in there it reads correctly and shows whats in the xml file. However if I close and open the program again and again it duplicates the entries in the xml file over and over again each time i open it.

Any suggestions?

```
 public partial class StaffCreate : Form
{
    public StaffCreate()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
    private void StaffCreate_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        if (!Directory.Exists(path + "\\stockbox  Documents"))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path + "\\stockbox Documents");
        if (!File.Exists(path + "\\stockbox Documents\\People_File.xml"))
        {
            XmlTextWriter xWriter = new XmlTextWriter(path + "\\stockbox Documents\\People_File.xml", Encoding.UTF8);
            xWriter.WriteStartElement("People");
            xWriter.WriteEndElement();
            xWriter.Close();
        }

        XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xDoc.Load(path + "\\stockbox Documents\\People_File.xml");
        foreach (XmlNode xNode in xDoc.SelectNodes("People/Person"))
        {
            Person p = new Person();
            p.name = xNode.SelectSingleNode("Name").InnerText;
            p.pass = xNode.SelectSingleNode("Password").InnerText;
            p.title = xNode.SelectSingleNode("Title").InnerText;
            people.Add(p);
            listView1.Items.Add(p.name);
        }



    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Person p = new Person();
        p.name = nameTxt.Text;
        p.pass = passTxt.Text;
        p.title = titleTxt.Text;
        people.Add(p);
        listView1.Items.Add(p.name);
        nameTxt.Text = "";
        passTxt.Text = "";
        titleTxt.Text = "";
    }

    private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            nameTxt.Text = people[listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index].name;
            passTxt.Text = people[listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index].pass;
            titleTxt.Text = people[listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index].title;
        }
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        remove();
        nameTxt.Text = "";
        passTxt.Text = "";
        titleTxt.Text = "";
    }

    void remove()
    {
        try
        {
            people.RemoveAt(listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index);
            listView1.Items.Remove(listView1.Items[0]);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        people[listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index].name = nameTxt.Text;
        people[listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index].pass = passTxt.Text;
        people[listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index].title = titleTxt.Text;
        listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text = nameTxt.Text;
    }

    private void StaffCreate_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        XmlDocument xDocument = new XmlDocument();
        xDocument.Load(path + "\\stockbox Documents\\People_File.xml");
        XmlNode xNode = xDocument.SelectSingleNode("People");

        foreach (Person p in people)
        {

            XmlNode xTnode = xDocument.CreateElement("Person");
            XmlNode xName = xDocument.CreateElement("Name");
            XmlNode xPass = xDocument.CreateElement("Password");
            XmlNode xTitle = xDocument.CreateElement("Title");

            xName.InnerText = p.name;
            xPass.InnerText = p.pass;
            xTitle.InnerText = p.title;

            xTnode.AppendChild(xName);
            xTnode.AppendChild(xPass);
            xTnode.AppendChild(xTitle);
            xDocument.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xTnode);
        }
        xDocument.Save(path + "\\stockbox Documents\\People_File.xml");
    }

}

class Person
{
    public string name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string pass
    {
        get;
        set;
    }


    public string title
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: the item remained in the xml because you don't remove any item from the xml. the reason for the duplication is: everytime you close the form, FormClosing execute and append all nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `StaffCreate_FormClosing` you're populating `xDocument` with the existing contents of the file (`xDocument.Load`) and then you add in everything in memory in the `for` loop, which contains whatever was in the file when it was loaded (duplicates minus deleted items plus added items).  As a result anything that wasn't deleted is added twice.  If you have everything in memory, there is no need to load from the file--you don't want any of those.

Answer (score 0):

In your StaffCreate_FormClosing method, you load the file and append new nodes for all people entities currently in memory. Removing all children from the people node (xnode) before appending should do the trick.

Comment: Removing all the children from that node gives an NullOutofRange Exception when you try to load the program with an empty file. I did remove people.Add(p) and place the loader into a button click event now it will only display the saved details in the file rather than dupe them

Answer (score 0):

You should either clear the xml file content every time, or track those `nodes` -- which in your codes, those person objects' status: whether they were created lately, or loaded from the existed xml file. Maybe like a little simple "ORM" thing.

And, maybe use `Path.Combine()` is better than doing the path string combination manually